# Looking to create utility that uses a cookie/token to determine which windows account should auto login after restart

Tags: windows, windows-10, wmi, boot

I have a machine with two windows accounts. I'm looking to create a program/utility that after a restart, will be able to recognize the presence of a cookie/file/token etc. and auto load one account if it is present and load the other if it is not.

pseudo code:

```
if(token){
    login(profile1)
}else{
    login(profile2)
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details?  What is this token, what puts it there, and at what point is it put there?  Would it be there when the machine is being shut down or is it possible its something remote to the system that may change while the system is down?

Comment: @PaulG, I'm trying to build a kiosk, that limits user interactivity,  to a single app but be able to be booted in a "service" mode with more advanced access (for software updates etc.). The kiosk will not have the ability to be accessed online or through other remote access. To enter the service mode account, the tech will input a few key strokes and a password into the kiosk app. My idea is that this action will leave behind a token/cookie/file and restart the computer. Once it restarts, the system will check for that toke and if found, boot into the admin account and not kiosk